# Finding a function to fit a curve.

Tags: functions, exponential-function, curves, regression, data-analysis

I would like to fit an equation to the curve shown below. A selection of the data points  (x,y) are given too.

I have tried to fit equations $y = a \, e^{(-b \, x)}$ and $y = a x^{-b}$ using software *minitab 19* without getting a good fit.

So if an equation can be found or suggested, that would be good.
[image: concave]

{{1., 3.97364}, {3., 2.65259}, {5., 2.12207}, {7., 1.81891}, {9.,
1.61681}, {11., 1.46983}, {21., 1.07533}, {31., 0.888459}, {41.,
0.77407}, {51., 0.694874}, {61., 0.63588}, {71., 0.589742}, {81.,
0.552379}, {91., 0.521322}, {101., 0.494974}, {201.,
0.349951}, {301., 0.278213}, {401., 0.226841}, {501.,
0.18593}, {601., 0.152562}, {701., 0.12521}, {801.,
0.102766}, {901., 0.0843466}, {1001., 0.0692285}, {2001.,
0.00960411}, {3001., 0.00133238}, {4001., 0.000184842}, {5001.,
0.0000256433}, {6001., 3.55751*10^-6}, {7001.,
4.93536*10^-7}, {8001., 6.84686*10^-8}, {9001., 9.49869*10^-9}}

Comment: Better to have a minimal description of this data.

Comment: @Yves Daoust agreed but not sure how to show curve for fitting without some data.

Comment: Try to plot the y- axis logarithmic. This might give you more intuition

Comment: The data is not enough.

Comment: What was wrong with the fit of the exponentials and what are you actually trying to achieve by fitting the data? If you can't find a satisfactory function then maybe Local Regression would be more useful.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I have put a link to a file with  10000 data points.

Comment: This is not what I mean. Data without context cannot be interpreted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Matlab's curve fitting tool, I got the following fit:

[image]

with the parameters as below:

```
General model Exp2:
     f(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =       3.513  (3.237, 3.788)
       b =     -0.1935  (-0.2215, -0.1655)
       c =      0.9278  (0.7994, 1.056)
       d =   -0.004471  (-0.006014, -0.002928)
```

and the goodness of fit as below:

```
Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 0.2513
  R-square: 0.9903
  Adjusted R-square: 0.9893
  RMSE: 0.09473
```

which seems reasonable.

Comment: thank you I will look into Matlab's curve fitting tool I have been trying so far with minitab